# Edit Total line in Oracle report

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I'm building a report with totals at the bottom, in Oracle reports. There are several Groups that have total lines and I would like the name of the Group to display before "Total". For example, lets say the Group is Fishing. I want it to dynamically show, "Fishing Total", for whatever the group may be? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boilerplate text item in the layout editor that takes the value of the group heading and adds additional text, e.g. `&GROUPTITLE Total`